# bring new data from csv file to delta table

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, aws-databricks

I have created new table with csv file with following code

```sql
%sql

SET spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled = true;

create table if not exists catlog.schema.tablename;

COPY INTO catlog.schema.tablename
  FROM (SELECT *  FROM 's3://bucket/test.csv') 
    FILEFORMAT = CSV 
    FORMAT_OPTIONS ('mergeSchema' = 'true', 'header' = 'true')
```

but i have new file with additional data. how can i load that please guide?

thanks

need to load new datafile in delta table

Answer (score 1):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below**

Make sure, to check whether the schema and file.csv data_type should match otherwise you will get an error.

**Please follow below syntax insert data from csv file**

```
%sql

copy into <catalog>.<schema>.<table_name>
  from "<file_loaction>/file_3.csv"
  FILEFORMAT = csv
  FORMAT_OPTIONS('header'='true','inferSchema'='True');
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the update. but will it take updated data or will it take all the rows from the file?

Comment: I also have tried but when i run the previous code which converts csv to parquet file and created delta table(where all columns become string or varchar) now if i run the copy command like your it will fail for the datatype mismatch or failed to merge incompatilble data types string and integer..

Comment: schema should match otherwise you will get an error as per approach.